# Firefox native support for userscripts - without addons

Tags: firefox, userscripts

I want to run some custom userscripts in Firefox but without add-ons like Greasemonkey.

A long time ago it was possible to do so by putting scripts in a folder named `userscripts\\` inside the Firefox user profile. I tried it but I think it no longer works.

So, is it possible to run userscripts in Firefox without installing add-ons?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. You cannot ***automatically*** run userscripts, nor can you use `GM_` functions unless you install an add-on like Tampermonkey or Violentmonkey (Greasemonkey became mostly useless with version 4).

Without such an extension, you can:

1. Manually run userscript code in the page's console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd>).
2. Or, [Convert the code to a bookmarklet](http://subsimple.com/bookmarklets/jsbuilder.htm), save it, and click the bookmark to run the code.

Or, if you don't trust other extension developers, you can [write your own extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons) to inject javascript automatically.  It's not that hard and you can get started with a simple `manifest.json` and a `content_scripts` js.
See ["Your first extension" on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension).